# Parallel foreach with configurable level of concurrency

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, locking

The purpose of this code is to let me loop over 100 items (up to `MAX_CONCURRENT` at a time), performing some action on them, and then return only once all items have been processed:

```
/// <summary>Generic method to perform an action or set of actions
/// in parallel on each item in a collection of items, returning
/// only when all actions have been completed.</summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The element type</typeparam>
/// <param name="elements">A collection of elements, each of which to
/// perform the action on.</param>
/// <param name="action">The action to perform on each element. The
/// action should of course be thread safe.</param>
/// <param name="MaxConcurrent">The maximum number of concurrent actions.</param>
public static void PerformActionsInParallel<T>(IEnumerable<T> elements, Action<T> action)
{
    // Semaphore limiting the number of parallel requests
    Semaphore limit = new Semaphore(MAX_CONCURRENT, MAX_CONCURRENT);
    // Count of the number of remaining threads to be completed
    int remaining = 0;
    // Signal to notify the main thread when a worker is done
    AutoResetEvent onComplete = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    foreach (T element in elements)
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref remaining);
        limit.WaitOne();
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                action(element);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error performing concurrent action: " + ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                Interlocked.Decrement(ref remaining);
                limit.Release();
                onComplete.Set();
            }
        }).Start();
    }
    // Wait for all requests to complete
    while (remaining > 0)
        onComplete.WaitOne(10); // Slightly better than Thread.Sleep(10)
}
```

I include a timeout on the `WaitOne()` before checking `remaining` again to protect against the rare case where the last outstanding thread decrements 'remaining' and then signals completion *between* the main thread checking 'remaining' and waiting for the next completion signal, which would otherwise result in the main thread missing the last signal and locking forever. This is faster than just using `Thread.Sleep(10)` because it has a chance to return immediately after the last thread completes.

Goals:

1. Ensure thread safety - I want to be sure I won't accidentally return too early (before all elements have been acted on), and be sure that I don't become deadlocked or otherwise stuck.
2. Add as little overhead as possible - minimizing amount of time that fewer than `MAX_CONCURRENT` threads are executing `action`, and returning as soon as possible after the final `action` has been performed.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using [PLINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @DanLyons nothing wrong with reinventing little wheels once in a while :p I actually hadn't ever used `.AsParallel()` before. I gave it a shot, and it works well!

Comment: @DanLyons Thanks, I gave PLINQ a shot but it only ever uses as many threads as I have logical processors, which is sub-optimal in my use case - because the threads aren't CPU-intensive, they're Server-bound, and I get the best speed up by 'queuing up' many requests on the server rather than just as many requests as I have cores. If PLINQ let you manually set the number of threads to use it would be an elegant solution.

Comment: @Alain [`WithDegreeOfParallelism`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd383719(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

I've made use of a `CountdownEvent` signal to avoid the use of the `remaining` integer and avoid the busy waiting involved in polling it with the unreliable `AutoResetEvent onComplete`:

```
public static void PerformActionsInParallel<T>(IEnumerable<T> elements, Action<T> action)
{
    int threads = MaxConcurrent ?? DefaultMaxConcurrentRequests;
    // Ensure elements is only enumerated once.
    elements = elements as T[] ?? elements.ToArray();
    // Semaphore limiting the number of parallel requests
    Semaphore limit = new Semaphore(MAX_CONCURRENT, MAX_CONCURRENT);
    // Count of the number of remaining threads to be completed
    CountdownEvent remaining = new CountdownEvent(elements.Count());

    foreach (T element in elements)
    {
        limit.WaitOne();
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                action(element);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error performing concurrent action: " + ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                remaining.Signal();
                limit.Release();
            }
        }).Start();
    }
    // Wait for all requests to complete
    remaining.Wait();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's one thing that is particularly disturbing me: the last `while` block. That's an example of [Busy waiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) and that's something that should be avoided IMO. A possible solution to this problem could be to store the `Thread` objects to a `List` and once you have created all the threads you run a `Thread.Join` for each thread on such list.

That being said, I'd suggest to take a look at [PLINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688(v=vs.110).aspx) and [TPL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx).

One last thing: I'd remove the `Console.WriteLine` in the `catch` block also. I'd say that the `Console.WriteLine` instruction should be used only in a `Main` method. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/dd997415(v=vs.110).aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460695(v=vs.110).aspx) for ways to handle exception when working in an async way.

Comment: Without wholesale switching to an out of the box parallel task runner, which loses me a lot of the flexibility I'm not showing here, is there any way I can finish this off without busy-waiting? My original intent was for the last line to read `while (remaining > 0) onComplete.WaitOne();` which would not be busy waiting at all, but as described, this ran into issues where the last two threads finished simultaneously.

Comment: @Alain In [this answer to a StackOverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584062/how-to-wait-for-thread-to-finish-with-net/2228508#2228508) they describe several methods. I'd suggest to take a look.

Comment: @Alain, I edited the answer with a possible way of solving the busy waiting problem. There's no code, but it should be pretty straight-forward.

Comment: @Alain, I think you should post that as an answer to the question or as another question if you want review on that also. In the help center you can read about [what you should do when someone answer your question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Thanks, will do. I gave PLINQ a shot but it only ever uses as many threads as I have logical processors, which is sub-optimal in my use case - because the threads aren't CPU-intensive, they're Server-bound, and I get the best speed up by 'queuing up' many requests on the server rather than just as many requests as I have cores.